# Dealing with Residues on the Real Axis - (Evaluation of Improper Integrals) Problem

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem**

Compute $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^a(x+2)} $, with $a \in \mathbb{R}$, using the Residue Theorem. Find the values of $a$ for which this procedure is valid.

**Attempt at a solution**
Looking at this integrand and letting $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^a(z+2)}$, it was/is easy to show that the integral does not converge for $a \le 0$ by just using direct integration via Calculus.

For $a>0$, I noticed that there were singularities at $z=0, -2$, both of which lie on the real axis, which means we cannot take the typical approach of the Residue Theorem by considering the upper semicircle $C_R$ and taking $R \to \infty$, etc.

The next thing I attempted to consider the region bounded by the quarter half circle $C_{R'}$ with radius $R$ and the positive $Re(z)$ and  $Im(z)$ axis, but also considering a quarter-circle with radius $\epsilon > 0$ about the origin in the same region since I have a singularity there. Contour integral for this region should be zero by Cauchy-Goursat, since the only possible singularity in this region would be at the origin (which I have avoided).

However, the computation becomes very messy, and this problem assumed to have no computational tools available when solving.

Am I on the right path? Or is there an easier approach to solving this question?

I also should note that, based on numerical computations on Mathematica, it seems to be valid for $0 < a < 1$.

**UPDATE (10/4/2013)**
Problem has been resolved!

For those who are curious. Brown/Churchill's Complex Variables (8th edition) text has a discussion on an almost identical problem on p. 283. Definitely a derp moment.

Comment: it should be $0<a<1$.

Comment: I know. But why?

Comment: @Archie to make sense to the integral , if $ a \ge 1 $ then it's not integrable in 0, see riemann criterias

Comment: Keyhole contour. Take a closed path, one straight line slightly above the positive real axis, a large almost-closed circle, back towards $0$ on a straight line slightly below the positive real axis, close the contour with an almost-closed small circle around $0$. You enclose the pole at $-2$.

Comment: @Archie: You need to work out the problem using the keyhole contour step by step and you will see why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we make a branch cut along the positive real axis, and define $\log(z)$ to be real along the top of the branch cut and $\log(z)+2\pi i$ along the bottom, then
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^a(z+2)}
=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^a(x+2)}
-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2\pi ia}\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^a(x+2)}\tag{1}
$$
where $\gamma_R$ is the contour $[0,R]\cup Re^{[0,2\pi i]}\cup[R,0]$. Note that the integral along $Re^{[0,2\pi i]}$ vanishes.

However, the integral along $\gamma_R$ contains the singularity at $z=-2$ where the residue is $\frac1{(-2)^a}=e^{-\pi ia}2^{-a}$. Therefore, the residue theorem and $(1)$ give us
$$
2\pi i e^{-\pi ia}2^{-a}
=\left(1-e^{-2\pi ia}\right)\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^a(x+2)}\tag{2}
$$
Solving this yields
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^a(x+2)}
&=\frac{2\pi i e^{-\pi ia}2^{-a}}{1-e^{-2\pi ia}}\\
&=\frac{2\pi i 2^{-a}}{e^{\pi ia}-e^{-\pi ia}}\\
&=\frac{\pi\,2^{-a}}{\sin(\pi a)}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Wow this is a beautiful answer. My complex analysis course skipped this section involving integration along branch cuts. Thank you!

Comment: Can someone explain a little further the first step. Where and why are we introducing the logarithm and idea of the branch cut? I can follow everything after that.

Comment: @Bennett $$z^{a} = e^{a \log z} = e^{a \log |z| + ia \arg z} = |z|^{a} e^{ia \arg z}$$

If $a$ is not an integer, $z^{a}$ has multiple branches.

Comment: Thank you @RandomVariable. Makes much more sense now.

Comment: One more question, I see why this procedure doesn't work at $a=1$, as you lose the original integral, but I don't fully understand the restriction $0<a<1$.

Comment: Since the integrand behaves like $ \displaystyle\frac{1}{2x^{a}}$ near $x=0$, the integral will only converge if $0 < a<  1$.